# cakephp not saving data

Tags: cakephp

For the life of me I can't figure out what's going wrong. When I debug the value of the `$order->save` operation, I get a `1` (which I assume to mean `true`). Here's what I'm doing:

```
$order = $this->Order->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array('Order.token' => urldecode($token))
));

debug($order);

$this->Order->id = $order['Order']['id'];
$orderData = array('Order' => array(
    'id' => $order['Order']['id'],
    'billing_email' => urldecode($payPalResponse['EMAIL']),
    'billing_name' => urldecode($payPalResponse['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTONAME']),
    'billing_address' => urldecode($payPalResponse['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET']),
    'billing_city' => urldecode($payPalResponse['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCITY']),
    'billing_state' => $payPalResponse['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTATE'],
    'billing_zipcode' => $payPalResponse['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOZIP']
));
debug($orderData);
$this->Order->save($orderData);
```

And here's what I'm getting:

```
controllers/markets_controller.php (line 149)
Array
(
    [Order] => Array
        (
            [id] => 13
            [token] => **************
            [player_id] => 1
            [status_id] => 1
            [timestamp] => 2012-02-15 12:09:24
            [date_filled] => February 15, 2012
        )

    [OrderItem] => Array
        (
        )

)

controllers/markets_controller.php (line 161)
Array
(
    [Order] => Array
        (
            [id] => 13
            [billing_email] => *********@************.com
            [billing_name] => Test User
            [billing_address] => 1 Main St
            [billing_city] => San Jose
            [billing_state] => CA
            [billing_zipcode] => 95131
        )

)
```

Why is it telling me that it's saving but it's not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I had tried to clear the cache before, but for some reason it didn't take. I finally cleared the cache file for the Order model, and that fixed it.